# How to transform a non-planar surface on a plane using a pair of 2D and 3D control points?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, transformation, homography

I have a set of control point pairs. One part of the pair is in world coordinates (3D). The other one is in pixel corrdinates of the image (2D).

My goal is to transform a surface you can see in this image onto a flat plane. The problem is that the surface is not perfectly flat, it kinda looks like a ribbon. Otherwise I could have used OpenCV's `getPerspectiveTransform()` or Matlab's `fitgeotrans()`.

I know that I can use OpenCV's `solvePnP()` or Matlab's `estimateWorldCameraPose()` to get the pose of the camera. The camera matrix is known and the image is rectified. But what is the next step then? How can I transform my ribbon shaped surface onto a flat plane, i.e. get an orthographic top view? That is the step, I'm stuck on.

Comment: there are different techniques in computer graphics literature about how to distribute the inevitable error when mapping a 3d surface to 2d plane. Typically there is a trade off between keeping lengths or angles without errors

Comment: @Micka Would you mind to name some of those methods? My surface is like a street going downhill. Perfectly straight, only the height varies. I have a projection of this surface as a camera image and what i want is to straighted it out. Like putting the ribbon on a flat table.

Comment: " a surface you can see in this image"... what image?

Comment: @tryman The image described in the first paragraphed, which contains my 2d control points.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding, the way you wrote it I was expecting to see an actual image that was missing.